Looking for SciFi Book name from 1990's or 80's about Mars
I read this book, it was trilogy I think.  It was about Mars being settled and had oceans.  There is an alien race there as well and the main characters had to eventually fight them.  The antagonist or aliens were large in size and humans had tough time beating them.  I read them around 96, so they must be from before that time.  Any help will be appreciated!  TIA.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall the cover art?

Not much, but showed some landscape of Mars I think.  Like red mountains.  There was a female character who was part of this human team that fought aliens/bad guys.

This was bugging me for sometime.  I did some search and read the synopsis on Mars Trilogy.  The term 'mega corporations' finally made sense to me.  There were five corporations based on five major military and economic powers of 90's (very biopic view of author if you ask me, with no mention of China and India).  The books are Red Mars, Green Mars and Blue Mars.

I didn't expect that; obviously KSR's Mars trilogy is the seminal work about terraforming Mars, but I'm pretty sure there are no actual aliens involved.  But if you're sure it's correct we can close this question.

Yeah, I'm going to read the Blue Mars again.  I think there were some genetically altered beings which led me to think that they were aliens.  Thank you!

Gene engineering leads to a longevity vaccine, and there are plenty of discussions on how Martian grown kids have longer lighter bones, can't handle Earth gravity or moisture, all through Blue Mars. The invasion bits were more like humans being dumped on Mars as flooding hit Earth.
